# Unable to run composer install on Magento 2.2.4 setup

Tags: php, composer-php, homebrew, magento2

I am currently trying to setup a existing Magento site on my localhost, after cloning the repository I'm unable to run composer install. I get the following error:

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for magento/framework 101.0.4 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.4].
- magento/framework 101.0.4 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
Problem 2
- Installation request for magento/magento2-base 2.2.4 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-base[2.2.4].
- magento/magento2-base 2.2.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
Problem 3
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.4 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.4].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.2.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
```

So it seems some PHP extensions are missing, however when trying to install them through brew, the following errors happen:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "php71-mcrypt" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching local taps...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Also if I use brew list it shows mcrypt already installed, however uninstalling that didn't help. I've also tried to completely re-install brew which also didn't help. 
I'm pretty inexperienced with both Magento and Brew, so if I'm missing any information here please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Which PHP version are you using on brew? (php -v)
I had similar when, even though brew services showed 7.1 running I was actually defaulting to 7.0.

Comment: Php -v returns 7.0.8 while MAMP and phpinfo(); both use Php 7.2

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following commands in the order shown:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew unlink php70 or 56 
brew install php71
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0
```

You can replace 7.0 by 7.1 in the command above to get version 7.1 of PHP

If the output of `php -v` still doesn’t echoes the version 7, simply type this command to update your path, it should do the magic, as stated on `php-osx.liip.ch` website.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

or

```
export PATH=”$(brew — prefix homebrew/php/php70)/bin:$PATH
```

or

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php70)/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I was able to get php -v to update to the same version as I'm using on MAMP (7.2.1), however now when trying to run composer install it throws out ~130 errors that PHP ~7.1 is the highest supported PHP version, so I'll try to reinstall a older version of MAMP and see if that works.